# Need Update last child row value in Master Parent row in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to update last child record value into parent record in SQL.I am stuck and haven't click any idea to resolve this.

I have table structure like that.

```
| id | parentID | Val|

  1      NULL      NULL
  2       1         0
  3       2         0
  4       3         0
  5       4         10
  10     NULL      NULL
  11      11        101
```

I have also attached table script.

```
create table #table1 (id int, parentId int,Val int)

INSERT INTO #table1 VALUES (1,null,null),
(2,1,0)
,(3,2,0)
,(4,3,0)
,(5,4,10)
,(10, null,null)
,(11,10,101)
```

The expected result would be

```
| id | parentID | Val|

  1      NULL      10
  10     NULL      101
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are wanting to do.  Please show us your desired result, based on your data sample.

Comment: Hi Andrew I have updated expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking for:

```
WITH CTE1 (MasterParentID, ChildID, Length) AS
(
    SELECT ID, ID, 0
    FROM #table1
    WHERE ParentID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CTE1.MasterParentID, T.ID, CTE1.Length + 1
    FROM CTE1 JOIN #table1 T ON CTE1.ChildID = T.ParentID
),
CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT
        MasterParentID,
        LastChildID = ChildID,
        Rank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MasterParentID ORDER BY Length DESC)
    FROM CTE1
)
UPDATE #table1
SET Val = (SELECT Val FROM #table1 C WHERE C.ID = CTE2.LastChildID)
FROM CTE2 JOIN #table1 P ON CTE2.MasterParentID = P.ID
WHERE CTE2.Rank = 1
```

This sets the value of row 1 to 10 and the value of row 10 to 101.

## Explanation

To explain this statement, I'll build it up in steps.

### Step 1: Find the master parent row for every child row.

```
WITH CTE1 (MasterParentID, ChildID, Length) AS
(
    SELECT ID, ID, 0
    FROM #table1
    WHERE ParentID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CTE1.MasterParentID, T.ID, CTE1.Length + 1
    FROM CTE1 JOIN #table1 T ON CTE1.ChildID = T.ParentID
)
SELECT * FROM CTE1
```

This query uses a [common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) (CTE) to recursively join parent rows to child rows. The result set is:

```
MasterParentID ChildID Length
1              1       0
10             10      0
10             11      1
1              2       1
1              3       2
1              4       3
1              5       4
```

The first two rows are returned by `SELECT ID, ID, 0 FROM #table1 WHERE ParentID IS NULL`. The remaining rows are returned by recursively joining the first two rows to `#table1`.

The `Length` column indicates the length of the chain from `MasterParentID` to `ChildID`. It will be used in Step 2 to identify the last link in each chain.

### Step 2: Find the last child row for each master parent row.

```
WITH CTE1 (MasterParentID, ChildID, Length) AS
(
    /* as above... */
),
CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT
        MasterParentID,
        LastChildID = ChildID,
        Rank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MasterParentID ORDER BY Length DESC)
    FROM CTE1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE2
WHERE CTE2.Rank = 1
```

This query takes the result set from Step 1, partitions them by `MasterParentID`, and returns only the row with the highest `Length` (rank #1) in each partition. The result set is:

```
MasterParentID LastChildID Rank
1              5           1
10             11          1
```

### Step 3: Update the value of each master parent row with the value of its last child row.

```
WITH CTE1 (MasterParentID, ChildID, Length) AS
(
    /* as above... */
),
CTE2 AS
(
    /* as above... */
)
UPDATE #table1
SET Val = (SELECT Val FROM #table1 C WHERE C.ID = CTE2.LastChildID)
FROM CTE2 JOIN #table1 P ON CTE2.MasterParentID = P.ID
WHERE CTE2.Rank = 1
```

This statement takes the result set from Step 2 and uses it to update `#table1`.